# log rotation problem on custom application

Tags: c++, c, linux, stderr

I have server program, written in C++. I usually start it as

```
db_net 2> log_file
```

I do not use anything special about logging, just print on stderr.

However sometimes, the log_file become huge. If I do

```
echo > log_file
```

It does not have effect, the file is not shrieked to zero. I know this worked 10 years ago, but now it does not.

Question is following:

- Can this be fixed from OS side somehow (I am running on Linux), without restarting the application
- if it can not be fixed from the OS, can I fix this from the application? I can close and open stderr, but I do not really know the filename where stderr points to, since it is redirected. C solution is OK too.

I know MySQL doing this with `flush logs;` and apache / nginx can do the same, however they know the filename and in their case is easy to reopen.

I know I can implement log file inside configuration, but currently I am looking for fast solution.

Filesystem is XFS.

Comment: Changing to [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog) rotating filesink would be an option?

Comment: @pptaszni, I dont need to keep the log. shrinking (deleting) the file will be enought for me. `rm log_file` will not really work, also I will not be able to watch the log after that

Comment: Mmm I see, hard to tell, as "it works on my machine". Maybe some of these commands: https://superuser.com/questions/90008/how-to-clear-the-contents-of-a-file-from-the-command-line

Comment: @pptaszni nothing work :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use append mode:

```
db_net 2>> log_file
```

Now when you manually truncate the file, the process will just continue to append to the new, empty file.

Comment: works. I know is append, but what is the difference from OS point of view?

Comment: The open(2) manpage has the following to say about O_APPEND: *Before each write(2), the file offset is positioned at the end of the file, as  if with  lseek(2).  The modification of the file offset and the write operation are performed as a single atomic step.* If you only truncate the file, the file offset remains set  and writing there will cause the OS to fill the file with blanks. Try `seek`ing to a 1GB offset in an empty file and writing a single character to see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Truncating the file by itself does not change the file offset of your `stderr` file descriptor.

From the application you can call:

```
ftruncate(2, 0);
lseek(2, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wish I can accept more than one answer of a question.

Answer (score 2):

You can also explore logrotate utility.

So, you can use append (2>>) to keep on writing in the errors in log file.
Then you can write a logrotate config something like this to rotate the log files:-

```
$ cat /etc/logrotate.d/log_file
<<path_of_log_file>>/log_file
{
  copytruncate      # To truncate original log file and make a copy of it.
  rotate 10         # To keep only last 10 files and remove older.
  daily             # To rotate the files daily
  size 10M          # Or Rotate when size reaches 10MB
  .....
}
```

There could be lot of different combinations in logrotate config.

Regards,
Yuvraj

Comment: this wont work. because file can not be reopen